# Error al acceder a elemento de array

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy teniendo problemas para acceder a elementos de un array, la key en el nombre tiene espacios (total weight), he probado con quiones, pegado y nada

```
$weight_variant = (array)$info_variant->packageInfo->total weight;

// Quiero acceder al elemento total weight de este array
array(5) {
  ["total weight"]=>
  string(5) "0.424"
  ["weight per box"]=>
  string(5) "0.424"
  ["Units Per Box"]=>
  string(4) "1000"
  ["box size"]=>
  string(9) "7 x 4 x 4"
  ["number of boxes"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: `$info_variant->packageInfo["total weight"]`

Comment: Me da error critico en wordpress

Comment: Listo ya vi que era, no puedes llamar el elemento ahi mismo, creas la variable y luego colocas esa variable con el elemento

Answer (score 0):

```
$weight_variant = (array)$info_variant->packageInfo;
echo $weight_variant["total weight"];
```

Comment: Cuando contestes a tu propia pregunta, considera explicar cuál ha sido el problema y cómo lo has resuelto. Dicho eso, ¿por qué te empeñas en forzar tu objeto a array? ¿Sabés que puedes acceder al objeto usando la notación `$elObjeto->laPropiedad`? Es decir, no es necesario forzar una conversión a array. Ya vi una pregunta anterior  con problemas y me parece que la solución que encontraste no era la mejor ... ahora sigues arrastrando problemas quizá por no haber entendido que hay que usar la notación de objetos cuando se trate de un objeto.

Comment: Forzo que sea array porque woocommerce pide que sea un array lo que le paso no un objeto